# Change root path of a VueJS project generated by cli

Tags: url, vue.js, github-pages

I created a *VueJS* project that I want to publish to *Github pages*.

Unfortunately I have a problem to resolve my asset because the github page URL is https://martindelille.github.io/eleform/ and asset like CSS files are referenced from the root directory (`/css/main.css`).

How can I change it?

Comment: Here is the source code if needed: https://martindelille.github.io/eleform/ (but I think it's not very well seen to post directly github project).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I followed the same [tutorial](https://medium.com/@codetheorist/vue-up-your-github-pages-the-right-way-955486220418) and needed to create a `vue.config.js` that looks like below in order to have the project assets resolve correctly.

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/your-project-name/'
}
```